# Python IRC bot /mode, /ban, /part, /join

Tags: python, bots, irc

Sooo I have an IRC bot based on Skybot (IRC bot). I've looked into its documentation but it's not stated how to do it. I'd like to make it join, quit, part, set mode and other irc commands, but typing them from chan. Simple example:

.part #hello ~ Parts the chan
.mode #hello +b Tom - Bans Tom

That's what it has in its documentation about events

> `@hook.event(irc_command)`
>
> Event hooks are called whenever a specific IRC command is issued. For
>   example, if you provide "*" as parameter, it will trigger on every
>   line. If you provide "PRIVMSG", it will only trigger on actual lines
>   of chat (not nick-changes).
>
> The first argument in these cases will be a two-element list of the
>   form ["#channel", "text"].

That's how a simple command works.

```
from util import hook, http


@hook.command
def calc(inp,say=None):
    'Does calculation'

    h = http.get_html('http://www.google.com/search', q=inp)

    m = h.xpath('//h2[@class="r"]/text()')

    if not m:
        say("I can't calculate " + inp + ".")

    res = ' '.join(m[0].split())

    say(res + ".")
```

**hook.py**

```
    import inspect
import re


def _hook_add(func, add, name=''):
    if not hasattr(func, '_hook'):
        func._hook = []
    func._hook.append(add)

    if not hasattr(func, '_filename'):
        func._filename = func.func_code.co_filename

    if not hasattr(func, '_args'):
        argspec = inspect.getargspec(func)
        if name:
            n_args = len(argspec.args)
            if argspec.defaults:
                n_args -= len(argspec.defaults)
            if argspec.keywords:
                n_args -= 1
            if argspec.varargs:
                n_args -= 1
            if n_args != 1:
                err = '%ss must take 1 non-keyword argument (%s)' % (name,
                            func.__name__)
                raise ValueError(err)

        args = []
        if argspec.defaults:
            end = bool(argspec.keywords) + bool(argspec.varargs)
            args.extend(argspec.args[-len(argspec.defaults):
                        end if end else None])
        if argspec.keywords:
            args.append(0)  # means kwargs present
        func._args = args

    if not hasattr(func, '_thread'):  # does function run in its own thread?
        func._thread = False


def sieve(func):
    if func.func_code.co_argcount != 5:
        raise ValueError(
                'sieves must take 5 arguments: (bot, input, func, type, args)')
    _hook_add(func, ['sieve', (func,)])
    return func


def command(arg=None, **kwargs):
    args = {}

    def command_wrapper(func):
        args.setdefault('name', func.func_name)
        _hook_add(func, ['command', (func, args)], 'command')
        return func

    if kwargs or not inspect.isfunction(arg):
        if arg is not None:
            args['name'] = arg
        args.update(kwargs)
        return command_wrapper
    else:
        return command_wrapper(arg)


def event(arg=None, **kwargs):
    args = kwargs

    def event_wrapper(func):
        args['name'] = func.func_name
        args.setdefault('events', ['*'])
        _hook_add(func, ['event', (func, args)], 'event')
        return func

    if inspect.isfunction(arg):
        return event_wrapper(arg, kwargs)
    else:
        if arg is not None:
            args['events'] = arg.split()
        return event_wrapper


def singlethread(func):
    func._thread = True
    return func


def regex(regex, flags=0, **kwargs):
    args = kwargs

    def regex_wrapper(func):
        args['name'] = func.func_name
        args['regex'] = regex
        args['re'] = re.compile(regex, flags)
        _hook_add(func, ['regex', (func, args)], 'regex')
        return func

    if inspect.isfunction(regex):
        raise ValueError("regex decorators require a regex to match against")
    else:
        return regex_wrapper
```

and **misc.py**, there's one hook.event command there:

```
#autorejoin channels
@hook.event('KICK')
def rejoin(paraml, conn=None):
    if paraml[1] == conn.nick:
        if paraml[0].lower() in conn.channels:
            conn.join(paraml[0])


#join channels when invited
@hook.event('INVITE')
def invite(paraml, conn=None):
    conn.join(paraml[-1])



@hook.event('004')
def onjoin(paraml, conn=None):
    # identify to services
    nickserv_password = conn.conf.get('nickserv_password', '')
    nickserv_name = conn.conf.get('nickserv_name', 'nickserv')
    nickserv_command = conn.conf.get('nickserv_command', 'IDENTIFY %s')
    if nickserv_password:
        conn.msg(nickserv_name, nickserv_command % nickserv_password)
        time.sleep(1)

    # set mode on self
    mode = conn.conf.get('mode')
    if mode:
        conn.cmd('MODE', [conn.nick, mode])

    # join channels
    for channel in conn.channels:
        conn.join(channel)
        time.sleep(1)  # don't flood JOINs

    # set user-agent
    ident, rev = get_version()
```

**main.py**, where conn things are defined.

```
class Input(dict):
    def __init__(self, conn, raw, prefix, command, params,
                    nick, user, host, paraml, msg):

        chan = paraml[0].lower()
        if chan == conn.nick.lower():  # is a PM
            chan = nick

        def say(msg):
            conn.msg(chan, msg)

        def reply(msg):
            if chan == nick:  # PMs don't need prefixes
                conn.msg(chan, msg)
            else:
                conn.msg(chan, nick + ': ' + msg)

        def pm(msg):
            conn.msg(nick, msg)

        def set_nick(nick):
            conn.set_nick(nick)

        def me(msg):
            conn.msg(chan, "\x01%s %s\x01" % ("ACTION", msg))

        def notice(msg):
            conn.cmd('NOTICE', [nick, msg])

        dict.__init__(self, conn=conn, raw=raw, prefix=prefix, command=command,
                    params=params, nick=nick, user=user, host=host,
                    paraml=paraml, msg=msg, server=conn.server, chan=chan,
                    notice=notice, say=say, reply=reply, pm=pm, bot=bot,
                    me=me, set_nick=set_nick, lastparam=paraml[-1])

    # make dict keys accessible as attributes
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self[key]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value
```

I don't really get how can I do it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't understand where you are stuck.

Comment: Well,I can make it to do everything, except /mode commands and /part for example. Let's say I want to ban John. I want to do it like, .ban John => something like conn.ban(inp). But conn.ban should do something like /mode +b (inp). Here I stuck. Not even an idea how to do it :'(.

Comment: Again, I don't understand the problem. Like you said, a ban is a `MODE` change, simply send the `MODE <#channel> +b <nickname>!*@*` command (or some other form of address banning) when the appropriate keyword is spoken.

Comment: Well, I've tried writing a ban command. Where I stuck:

from util import hook


    @hook.command
    def ban(inp,conn=None,me=None,say=None,chan="",nick=""):
    admins = ('Tom')
    if nick not in admin:
    say("no")
    if nick in admin:
    conn.cmd('MODE',chan, "+b",inp)

I'm almost sure my mistake is in conn.cmd('MODE',chan,"=b",inp), but no idea how to fix it ;'(.

Comment: I'm still trying to fix this one, any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Use `('MODE',chan,"+b",inp)` for a ban `-b` to remove the ban.